# Block specific URL from hitting your site

Tags: .htaccess, hyperlink, http-referer

All,
I'm getting a lot of traffic to my website from back links and it's affecting my google analytics. Is there a way to block a specific website from accessing my website through .htaccess? For example purposes, if I want to block http://foo.com how would I do that? Is there a better way then .htaccess?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean "block a website"? Do you mean block all visits from with that referring website?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Yes, that is what I mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the following to your .htaccess file

```
#if the request came from foo.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://foo\.com$
#then serve it a 403 Forbidden
RewriteRule . - [F,L]
```